# Dynamic Shader Linkage not working in DirectX 11

Tags: directx

Hi so I'm trying to get dynamic shader linkage working in my dx11 project. It complies fine but does not seem to do anything. I believe the problem is CreateClassInstance, not sure what values to pass for the offsets

I create the instance with this

```
ID3D11ClassInstance* instance = nullptr;
        mShaders->GetPixelShader()->GetClassLinkage()->CreateClassInstance("EvenSplitter", 0, 0, 0, 0, &instance);
        mShaders->GetPixelShader()->GetDynamicLinkage()[0] = instance;
```

and my shader code is:

```
Texture2D shaderTexture;
SamplerState SampleType;

RWTexture2D<float4> writeTex : register(u1);

struct PixelInputType
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

 interface iSplitPixels
 {
    void Split(PixelInputType input);
 };

 class SplitOdd : iSplitPixels
 {
    void Split(PixelInputType input){
        [branch]if(  !fmod(input.position.x + input.position.y, 2.0f) ){
            writeTex[input.position.xy / 2] = shaderTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex);
        }
    }
 };

 class SplitEven : iSplitPixels
 {
    void Split(PixelInputType input){

        [branch]if(  fmod(input.position.x + input.position.y, 2.0f) ){
            writeTex[input.position.xy / 2 ] = shaderTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex);
        }
    return;
    }
 };

 iSplitPixels spliter;

float4 main(PixelInputType input) : SV_TARGET
{
    float4 textureColor = {  0, 0, 0, 1.0f };

    spliter.Split(input);

    return textureColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out. What we need to do is put the classes into a buffer, like so

```
cbuffer ClassInstances: register(b0)
{

   class SplitEven : iSplitPixels; //can put the body in as well if you like
   class SplitOdd : iSplitPixels;

}
```

We can then use CreateClassInstance to chose which class to instantiate with the first variable. The second corresponds to the buffer number used to house the classes, the third variable is used if our classes have member variables so we would have to provide an offset in memory.

```
mShaders->GetPixelShader()->GetClassLinkage()->CreateClassInstance("EvenSplitter", 0, 0, 0, 0, mShaders->GetPixelShader()->GetClassInstanceArray());
```